# How to set the border for the last element using CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I am having the elements as below

```
<div class="main">
    <h3> first </h3>
    <div> content </div>
    <h3> Second </h3>
    <div> content </div>
    <h3> third </h3>
   <div> content </div>
</div>
```

I have set the border color for the third h3 element through the css, i have tried like this

```
<style>
.main h3:last-child{
border : 1px solid;
}
</style>
```

but it does not work, is there any other way to achieve my requirement

Comment: With this solution you are targeting the last child ONLY IF it's an H3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use last-of-type, like this:

```
.main h3:last-of-type {
  border : 1px solid;
}
```

H3 has no child element in this case, you want to select the last h3  (type)

Example:

```css
.main h3:last-of-type {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h3> first </h3>
  <div> content </div>
  <h3> Second </h3>
  <div> content </div>
  <h3> third </h3>
  <div> content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.main div ~ h3 ~ div ~ h3` would also work, but this is **way** cleaner, and supported all the way back to IE9 (though not IE8).

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you could use something about the element (a class, its contents, etc.) to target it.

Barring that, [Camille's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42950427/157247) is what to do for even vaguely-modern browsers.

***If*** you had to support IE8, which doesn't do `:last-of-type`, you could still do it with a sibling combinator. But it's ugh-lee:

```css
.main div ~ h3 ~ div ~ h3 {
 border : 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <h3> first </h3>
    <div> content </div>
    <h3> Second </h3>
    <div> content </div>
    <h3> third </h3>
   <div> content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`h3:last-child` means "A element of type 'h3' that is the last child of its parent". It does not mean "The last element of type 'h3' in its parent". Since you have a div after your h3, the h3 is not the last child.

You want `:last-of-type`

hence,

```
.main>h3:last-of-type {
   border : 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.main::nth-child(4){
  border : 1px solid;
}
```